# Iterating through multiple collections in python

Tags: python, list

So I've been having a little trouble coming up with a with to do the following.

Let's start with the collections.

```
Names = ['Brian', 'Tom', 'Mary']
LifeStats = [{'age':'25', 'gender':'male'},{'age':'27', 'gender':'male'},{'age':'35', 'gender':'female'}]
Children = [[{'Name':'Mike', 'Age':'5'}, {'Name':'Lisa', 'Age':'9'},][{'Name':'Paul':'Age':'5'}],[{'Name':'Pete', 'Age':'2'}{'Name':'Nicky', 'Age':'11'}{'Name':'Jerry', 'Age':'2'}]]
```

Each list is derived from different calls to an API.   All the collections are tied together.  The first list value for each collection is tied together.  But I can't seem to figure out how to iterate the lists in a way that I could print something like this..

```
Name:Brian
Age:25
Gender:Male
Children:  Mike, Lisa<br>
Name=Tom
Age:27
Gender:Male
Children:   Paul, Pete, Nicky
```

Where I am having trouble is iterating the children out since there are multiple children to each parent since that is a list of lists of dictionaries that is tied to 2 different lists of dictionaries.

I am relative newbie at coding Python so I apologize if this is an obvious thing to solve

Answer (score 3):

So first things first, you can element-wise pair up the lists using `zip`.

```
>>> people = zip(Names,LifeStats,Children)
>>> people
[('Brian', {'gender': 'male', 'age': '25'}, [{'Age': '5', 'Name': 'Mike'}, {'Age': '9', 'Name': 'Lisa'}]),
 ('Tom', {'gender': 'male', 'age': '27'}, [{'Age': '5', 'Name': 'Paul'}]),
 ('Mary', {'gender': 'female', 'age': '35'}, [{'Age': '2', 'Name': 'Pete'}, {'Age': '11', 'Name': 'Nicky'}, {'Age': '2', 'Name': 'Jerry'}])]
```

Then iterate through that, parse stuff, and do your printing:

```
for person in people:
    # Grab relevant info from the lists and dictionaries
    name = person[0]
    age = person[1]['age']
    gender = person[1]['gender']
    children = [i['Name'] for i in person[2]]
    # Do your printing and formatting
    print('Name: {}'.format(name))
    print('Age: {}'.format(age))
    print('Gender: {}'.format(gender))
    print('Children: {}'.format(', '.join(children)))
    print('\n')
```

Output

> Name: Brian
>   Age: 25
>   Gender: male
>   Children: Mike, Lisa
>
> Name: Tom
>   Age: 27
>   Gender: male
>   Children: Paul
>
> Name: Mary
>   Age: 35
>   Gender: female
>   Children: Pete, Nicky, Jerry

Comment: @user1767754 the `', '.join(children)` part takes care of that. Try it on the Python console with a list of one child and one with several.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Your suggestion helped me figure out the easiest way to do what I needed to do!